# Auto updating field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am working on a form that requires an auto updating field.  The requested format is last two digits of the year followed by "-01".  Is there a way to do this without using visual studio and only using the web and Designer 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Try to create calculated field (in this way you will have problem getting current year for the formula
2. Write a simple CSR JavaScript (JSLink) that calculates the value and fills the value on pre-render in the new form. You can specify JSLink in the new form or edit form web part settings.

JSLink samples:

1. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a
2. http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013